# Dart: How to get total length of all list values in a list of map?

Tags: list, dart, dictionary

I have this:

```
final data = [
    {
      'name': 'Team A',
      'team': ['Klay Lewis', 'Ehsan Woodard', 'River Bains']
    },
    {
      'name': 'Team B',
      'team': ['Toyah Downs', 'Tyla Kane']
    },
    {
      'name': 'Team C',
      'team': [
        'Jacky Chan',
        'Yalor Rowds',
        'Tim Bourla',
        'Levis Strauss',
        'Jane Smow'
      ]
    }
  ];
```

I want to find the quickest way to get a sum of all team members. In the above example, it would be 3 + 2 + 5 = 10 total members.

The real world data will have thousands of teams, so quickest way needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fold` will get the job done.

```dart
final int totalLength = data.fold(0, (sum, obj) => sum + obj['team'].length);
```

Comment: Thanks. I added an extra cast in there to make it work. `int totalLength =
        data.fold(0, (sum, obj) => sum + (obj['team'] as List<String>).length);`

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

const data = [...];

void main(List<String> args) {
  var members = data.map((e) => (e['team'] as List).length).sum;
  print(members);
}
```